# Javascript Map Reduce Multiple Fields in Arrays of Objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to summarize an multiple arrays of objects (key value pairs).  I found another post using a map reduce function, but I'm not sure how to translate that to return by multiple keys. Current solution shows reduced and mapped by month, but I need to reduce and map by month and salesperson. I have d3 drop-down menus in my HTML index with months and salespersons which include a selection of all in both categories.

When a single salesperson and all months are selected the data_array looks like this:

```
data_array =  [{salesperson: 'Beth', month: 'Feb', 'value ly': 8, 'value plan': 10, 'value ty' : 14},
    {salesperson: 'Beth', month: 'Jan', 'value ly': 16, 'value plan': 18, 'value ty' : 20},
    {salesperson: 'Beth', month: 'Feb', 'value ly': 12, 'value plan': 15, 'value ty' : 18},
    { salesperson: 'Beth', month: 'Jan', 'value ly': 13, 'value plan': 21, 'value ty' : 25}]
```

When all salespersons and all months are selected the data_array looks like this:

```
data_array = [{salesperson: 'Joe', month: 'Jan', 'value ly': 10, 'value plan': 20, 'value ty' : 30},
{salesperson: 'Joe', month: 'Jan', 'value ly': 14, 'value plan': 18, 'value ty' : 22},  
{salesperson: 'Greg', month: 'Feb', 'value ly': 5, 'value plan': 10, 'value ty' : 12},
{ salesperson: 'Greg', month: 'Feb', 'value ly': 7, 'value plan': 9, 'value ty' : 5},
{salesperson: 'Joe', month: 'Feb', 'value ly': 12, 'value plan': 14, 'value ty' : 16},
{ salesperson: 'Joe', month: 'Feb', 'value ly': 15, 'value plan': 16, 'value ty' : 13},
{salesperson: 'Beth', month: 'Feb', 'value ly': 8, 'value plan': 10, 'value ty' : 14},
{salesperson: 'Beth', month: 'Jan', 'value ly': 16, 'value plan': 18, 'value ty' : 20},
{salesperson: 'Beth', month: 'Feb', 'value ly': 12, 'value plan': 15, 'value ty' : 18},
{ salesperson: 'Beth', month: 'Jan', 'value ly': 13, 'value plan': 21, 'value ty' : 25}]
```

Using the first result of data_array my code runs as follows:

```
 data_array =  [{salesperson: 'Beth', month: 'Feb', 'value ly': 8, 'value plan': 10, 'value ty' : 14},
        {salesperson: 'Beth', month: 'Jan', 'value ly': 16, 'value plan': 18, 'value ty' : 20},
        {salesperson: 'Beth', month: 'Feb', 'value ly': 12, 'value plan': 15, 'value ty' : 18},
        { salesperson: 'Beth', month: 'Jan', 'value ly': 13, 'value plan': 21, 'value ty' : 25}]
        
    let reduced_data_array = data_array.reduce((prev,next)=>{
       if (next.month in prev) {
             prev[next.month]['value ly'] += next['value ly'];
             prev[next.month]['value plan'] += next['value plan'];
             prev[next.month]['value ty'] += next['value ty'];
       } else {
             prev[next.month] = next;
       return prev;
    }, {});
        
let mapped_reduced_data = Object.keys(reduced_data_array).map(month => reduced_data_array[month]);

return mapped_reduced_data
```

When selecting a single salesperson and all months this returns the data without issue in this format (ex: Beth and all months selected):

[image]

I would like to alter my map and reduce functions when all salespersons and all months are selected (second dataset) to return the following:

[image]

Comment: No typo? `data_array.reduce(prev,next)=>{`

Comment: Yes missing a "("

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

You don't need `map` or `reduce`. Just a simple `filter` will do exactly what you want.

```
data_array.filter(
  obj => LIST_OF_SALESPERSON.includes(obj.salesperson)) && LIST_OF_MONTHS.includes(obj.month)
);
```

To test this behaviour i created a simple example using the data you provided. Simply click on "**Run code snippet**":

```js
// Data
const data_array = [{salesperson: 'Joe', month: 'Jan', 'value ly': 10, 'value plan': 20, 'value ty' : 30},
{salesperson: 'Joe', month: 'Jan', 'value ly': 14, 'value plan': 18, 'value ty' : 22},  
{salesperson: 'Greg', month: 'Feb', 'value ly': 5, 'value plan': 10, 'value ty' : 12},
{ salesperson: 'Greg', month: 'Feb', 'value ly': 7, 'value plan': 9, 'value ty' : 5},
{salesperson: 'Joe', month: 'Feb', 'value ly': 12, 'value plan': 14, 'value ty' : 16},
{ salesperson: 'Joe', month: 'Feb', 'value ly': 15, 'value plan': 16, 'value ty' : 13},
{salesperson: 'Beth', month: 'Feb', 'value ly': 8, 'value plan': 10, 'value ty' : 14},
{salesperson: 'Beth', month: 'Jan', 'value ly': 16, 'value plan': 18, 'value ty' : 20},
{salesperson: 'Beth', month: 'Feb', 'value ly': 12, 'value plan': 15, 'value ty' : 18},
{ salesperson: 'Beth', month: 'Jan', 'value ly': 13, 'value plan': 21, 'value ty' : 25}];


// Function containing the logic behind the filter
function getDataByFilter (filters) {
  return data_array.filter(
  obj => (filters.salesperson.length == 0 || filters.salesperson.includes(obj.salesperson)) && (filters.month.length == 0 || filters.month.includes(obj.month))
);
}

// Get all data here by passing to the function the desired filters
var data_no_filter = getDataByFilter({
  "salesperson": [],
  "month": []
});

var data_by_salesperson = getDataByFilter({
  "salesperson": ["Greg", "Beth"],
  "month": []
});

var data_by_salesperson_and_month = getDataByFilter({
  "salesperson": ["Greg", "Beth"],
  "month": ["Feb"]
});


// Print to console the data we have previously filtered
console.log("No filters: %o", data_no_filter);
console.log("By SalesPerson: %o", data_by_salesperson);
console.log("By SalesPerson and Month: %o", data_by_salesperson_and_month);
```

## How to implement?

Just pass to the `getDataByFilter` function an `Object` like the ones in the example, where you'll add the data you got from the select and you will receive the filtered data

Comment: Thanks for your help.  This is helpful even though I found another solution and posted it to answers.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found an answer that works after searching for a few days AFTER I posted this:

```
    const reduce_data = data_array.reduce((result, d) => {
        let key = `${d.RSM}_${d.Month}`;
        result[key] = result[key] || {...d, 'value ly':0, 'value plan':0, 'value ty':0};
        result[key]['value ly'] += +d['value ly'];
        result[key]['value plan'] += +d['value plan'];
        result[key]['value ty'] += +d['value ty'];

        return result
    }, {});
    const data_result = Object.values(reduce_data);
```